# Zend2 element/select issue with array

Tags: php, zend-framework2

Maybe someone knows how to fix this issue.

For example:

```
//id in database is 1 (so it should select first element)

$dataArray = [
1 => 'Test 1',
2 => 'Test 2',
3 => '1',
]

$type = new Element\Select('type');
$type->setValueOptions($dataArray);
```

It will create normal select box, but when data will be auto selected, options will marked as selected 1 and 3 (no matter that's not multi select).

This problem appears when array is loaded from database and value in array is equal for label.

Any help?

Comment: Hi arijus, which version of zf2 u use, never meet this kind of problem with 2.3

Comment: 2.2 v. Yep, its very strange behavior, first time for me too. I forgot to mention that i'm using fieldsets for that form..

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. 
When printing element, value was set like object.